# How to send a single json response from a vb.net linq query using the select option

Tags: json, vb.net, linq

I have a function where if I feed it an id of 0, I want to send back an json array of people.

```
[
    {
      "firstname": "santa",
      "lastname": "claus",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "firstname": "john",
      "lastname": "smith",
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
```

If I feed it and id of 1, I want to send back just a single entry, no array.

```
{
  "firstname": "john",
  "lastname": "smith",
  "id": 1
}
```

Using jsonresult, I can easily rename and select properties with out mapping it to a class.

The array version works. However, I can't figure out hot to do the single response. I tried to methods:

1. It doesn't let me use .single with the "select" option to define an anonymous class in the same statement
2. When I try to use q(0), I get the following error:                 'System.MissingMemberException: 'No default member found for type 'DbQuery(Of VB$AnonymousType_1(Of String,String,Integer))'.'

Is it possible using the select option to send a single entry back?

```
 Function get_people_jsonresult(Optional id As Integer = 0) As JsonResult
        Dim q As Object
        If id = 0 Then
            q = From c In db.dtb_people.OrderBy(Function(x) x.c_lastname).ToList Select New With {
            .firstname = c.c_firstname,
            .lastname = c.c_lastname,
            .id = c.c_Id
            }
            Return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        ElseIf id = 1 Then
            'how do I do a single request? .single doesn't work vs. tolist
            q = From c In db.dtb_people.Where(Function(x) x.c_Id = id).Single Select New With {
            .firstname = c.c_firstname,
            .lastname = c.c_lastname,
            .id = c.c_Id
            }
            'is it possible to select the first entry before being sent back here?
            Return Json(q(0), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

        End If

    End Function
```

updated. I found it is possible to do an anonymous class this way, but still curious if possible to do it in the same statement as the single:

```
Dim c As dtb_people = db.dtb_people.Where(Function(x) x.c_Id = 1).Single

Return Json(New With {
     .firstname = c.c_firstname,
     .lastname = c.c_lastname,
     .id = c.c_Id.ToString
     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall what each of the parts of the query does and what it operates on:

- `Where()` filters an enumerable based on some criteria, producing a new enumerable containing only the matching elements.
- `Single()` operates on an enumerable to reduce it to a single element (so the result is no longer enumerable).
- `Select()` operates on an enumerable to transform each of its elements to a new form, producing a new enumerable containing the new elements.

You are attempting to use `Single` to get a single element from your table and *then* `Select` it into a different form.  This won't work because `Select` doesn't operate on a single element.  It operates on an enumerable.  So, you need to change the order of operations here.

Try it like this instead:

```
    q = (From c In db.dtb_people.Where(Function(x) x.c_id = id) Select New With {
       .firstname = c.c_firstname,
       .lastname = c.c_lastname,
       .id = c.c_id
    }).Single()
```

Notice I have wrapped the whole `From` expression in parenthesis up through the end of the `Select` portion and then applied `Single` at then end.

Note: if it is possible that the `id` you are querying for might not exist in the database, you might want to use `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Single()`.  `Single()` will throw an exception if there is not exactly one result (i.e. if there are no results or more than one result).  `SingleOrDefault()` will return null if there are no results, and will throw an exception only if there is more than one result.

Comment: Excellent, it worked! I'll mark it as the answer. However, is it possible when getting back a list of items and grab the first item to be fed to the json function like "Return Json(q(0), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)"?

Comment: If you want the first item from an enumerable you can use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()` respectively.